# Call ASP validations using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I plan to put all my validations in my javascript function. However, I have ASP RequiredFieldValidator, RegularExpressionValidator because I have to display the errors in ValidationSummary. I am using ASP.NET 1.1. How do I call and fire these ASP validations in javascript?

The reason I wanted to fire these ASP validations in javascript is because they are not working by themselves! I noticed in Firefox, when I click a button and the page reloads..they display but wont be retained until the loading of the page completes. Any ideas?

Comment: There are so many ways to do validations. Let me know for what exactly you are looking? Do you want to code client side? or you just want to show the error messages on client side?

Comment: Yes, I want to show the error messages on client side.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" ShowMessageBox="True"
 ShowSummary="False" ValidationGroup="groupName" />
```

*You should use the same ValidationGroup text on all validation controls and add a ValidationSummary with the ValidationGroup and* `ShowMessageBox="true"`

Comment: unfortunately, validationgroup is not supported in ASP 1.1 yet

Comment: The reason I wanted to fire these ASP validations in javascript is because they are not working by themselves! I noticed in Firefox, when I click a button and the page reloads..they display but wont be retained until the loading of the page completes. Any ideas?